# An "E20: Mark not set" when try to update info in VIM

Tags: vim

I met a trouble with updating the info in VIM with function. My code is as following:

```viml
map <F4> :call UpdateTitle()<cr>'s
"Update the latest modification time and filename
function UpdateTitle()
    normal m'
    execute '/# *Last modified:/s@:.*$@\=strftime(": %Y-%m-%d %H:%M")@'
    normal ''
    normal mk
    execute '/# *Filename:/s@:.*$@\=": ".expand("%:t")@'
    execute "noh"
    normal 'k
    echohl WarningMsg | echo "Successful in updating the copyright." | echohl None
endfunction
```

When I press <kbd>F4</kbd> in VIM, it DOES work. BUT it always show an error message as `E20: Mark not set`. I thought the error happens at the last two line. But I cannot find out a solution.
I tried `echoerr`. It works, but not what I what.
I tried `echomsg` and `echo` alone. But it does not work. No message output. But a error message shows as `E20: Mark not set`.

Furthermore, even if I delete the whole echo line. The same error shows again.

VIM version is 7.0.237.

Comment: Vim 7.0 is from 2006 and _very_ outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.3; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution, it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
E20: Mark not set
```

Usually this means you are trying to jump to  a non-existant mark.

Take a look at your map:

```
map <F4> :call UpdateTitle()<cr>'s
```

What is the `'s` at the end? Do you have mark `s`?

- This error msg will clear your message (echoed in your function). That's why you cannot see it.
- The function worked because it happened before your "typo"

Comment: Is this a crash or getting stuck in some vim IDE state?

Answer (score 4):

If you're seeing `E20: Mark not set` by **accident**, you can proceed with the command you were trying to run.

E.g. hit `i` to enter edit mode and the message will go away.

I was trying to type a backtick <kbd>`</kbd> followed by letters, thinking I was in edit mode, which happens to be the way you jump to a mark (see [Using marks](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks)).